# Using Backbone collections in the right way to pass them in the sub view and then in the template engine

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, backbone.js, template-engine

I'm trying understand how to work with `Backbone` `collections` and to pull them inside the relative `template engine` created by a `sub view`.

This is the logic i tried in my app:

[image]

My `ajax request` returns me this object:

```
{
    "products":[
        {
            "id":"43",
            "text":"Sunset Chips",
            "image":"43.png"
        },{
            "id":"107",
            "text":"Pringles Hot & Spicy",
            "image":"107.png"
        }
    ],
    "brands":[
        {
            "id":"132",
            "text":"P&G",
            "image":"132.png"
        },{
            "id":"27",
            "text":"Kinder",
            "image":"27.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

I grab it with `jQuery`'s `$.ajax` method and manage it for my Backbone app here in my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var search = {};

search.app = {};
search.app.id = "#search-results";

search.product = {};
search.product.defaults = {
    id:0,
    text:"<?php echo __('No results here');?>",
    image:"<?php echo $this->webroot;?>files/product/default.png",
};

$(function(){

    var SearchApp = new Search.Views.App({
        id:"#search-results"
    });

    var ProductList = new Search.Collections.Products();
    var subView;

    function parseResults (response, search) {

        for (var i = response.products.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            ProductList.add([new Search.Models.Product(response.products[i])]);
        };

        subView = new Search.Views.Product ({
            collection:ProductList,
            id:"#product-results",
            template:"#results-product-template" // solo in this.options.template
        });

        updateResults();
    }

    function updateResults () {
        console.log('updateResults: Ritorno il risultato quando hunter riceve una risposta dal server');
        if ($('#search-results').length == 0) {
            $('div.main > section:first-child').before('<section id="search-results"></section>');
        }
        SearchApp.renderProductCollection(subView);
    }

    $('#search-results .close').on('click', function () {
        $('#search-results').animate({height:0}, 500, function () {
            $(this).remove();   
        })
    });

    var callbacks = {
        on_response:parseResults // function presente in backbone.search.js
    };

    $('#hunter').hunter({url:'<?php echo $this->request->base; ?>/searches/default_search', callback:callbacks, ajax_params:{limit:10, term:'%%'}});

});
</script>
```

This is my Backbone application:

```
var Search = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Templates:{}
}

Search.Models.Product = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: search.product.defaults || {},
    initialize:function () {
        console.log("initialize Search.Models.Product");
        this.on("change", function (){
            console.log("chiamato evento change del Model Search.Models.Product");
        });
        this.on("change:text", function () {
            console.log("chiamato evento change:text del Model Search.Models.Product");
        });
    }
});

Search.Collections.Products = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Search.Models.Product,
    initialize:function () {
        console.log("initialize Search.Collections.Products");
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.length);
        console.log(this.models);
    }
});

Search.Views.App = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize:function () {
        console.log("initialize Search.Views.App");
        this.$prd = this.$('#product-results');
    },
    render:function () {

        console.log("render Search.Views.App");
    },
    renderProductCollection:function (subView) {
        console.log("Search.Views.App > renderProductCollection");
        console.log('subView.getTemplate() => ' + subView.getTemplate());
        $(this.id).html(subView.getTemplate());
    }
});

Search.Views.Product = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize:function () {
        console.log("initialize Search.Views.Product");
    },
    getTemplate:function (data) {
        if (data == null || data == undefined) {
            data = this.collection.toJSON() || this.model.toJSON(); 
        }
        var template = Handlebars.compile($(this.options.template).html());
        console.log(data);
        return '<ul id="product-results" class="w-1-4">' + template(data) + '</ul>';
    },
    render:function () {
        console.log("render Search.Views.Product");
        return this;
    }
});
```

The `Handlesbar` template is simply this:

```
<ul class="w-1-4">
    <li>
        <b>Products</b>
    </li>
   {{#each products}}
    <li>
        <a href="{{url}}">
            <div class="origin {{type}}" title="{{name}}"><img src="'.$this->webroot.'img/icons/16/origin/{{icon}}"></div>
        </a>
        <div>
            <a href="{{url}}" class="font-default-bold {{model}}-btn">{{name}}</a>
            {{#support}}<a href="{{support.url}}" class="font-small">{{support.name}}</a>{{/support}}
        </div>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

My problem is when I try to parse the data inside the `Handlesbar` template, since I've parsed my data inside the `sub view collection`, I have an `Array` structured like this:

```
[
    {
        "id":"43",
        "text":"Sunset Chips",
        "image":"43.png"
    },{
        "id":"107",
        "text":"Pringles Hot & Spicy",
        "image":"107.png"
    }
]
```

With this data I don't have the `products` object anymore due to the `parseResults` in the view, where I put the ajax inside the collection.

How can I parse the `products` array without `products` prop name, or how I can keep the data in the right way?

I know in my app I can do something like this to solve the problem:

```
var container = new array();
container['products'] = this.collection.toJSON();
data = container;

var template = Handlebars.compile($(this.options.template).html());
return '<ul id="product-results" class="w-1-4">' + template(data) + '</ul>';
```

But is this the right way or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use $.ajax if you are working with Backbone.

Use collection.fetch
http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch

Also looks like the server is not giving you the answer as you need, so Backbone has its own parse:
http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse

Also I'm a fan of logic less template. So the iteration through the collection must be in the view and not in the template. Also please check this(specially point two):
http://ozkatz.github.io/avoiding-common-backbonejs-pitfalls.html

Use a collection in the right way, then to render it, in the view you could listen to the add or reset event and populate the collection in that way.
this.collection.on('add', this.render); //get model by model
this.collection.on('reset', this.render); //get all models (you need to specify in the fetch call a parameter {reset : true}

Comment: No problem, this question involves too much topics, if with the re-factor of code that you will do, you get new questions(specific by area, like fetch, or render, etc) please create it and we will be helping you.